# There is no match while comparing the columns in df.head and df.columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, training-data

So I'm working with the Titanic Dataset provided at https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv and
upon calling `df.head()` I recieved the following output

```
survived    sex age n_siblings_spouses  parch   fare    class   deck    embark_town alone
    0   male    22.0    1   0   7.2500  Third   unknown Southampton n
    1   female  38.0    1   0   71.2833 First   C   Cherbourg   n
    1   female  26.0    0   0   7.9250  Third   unknown Southampton y
    1   female  35.0    1   0   53.1000 First   C   Southampton n
    0   male    28.0    0   0   8.4583  Third   unknown Queenstown  y
```

But when I call `df.columns`, I get the following as output

```
Index(['sex', 'age', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'fare', 'class', 'deck',
       'embark_town', 'alone'],
      dtype='object')
```

The "survived" column is missing when comparing head and columns method.

I'm confused about what to do next because when i try to pop the 'survived' column it gives me a keyError.

Output:

```
KeyError: 'survived'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'survived'
```

Comment: Could you provide your code completely? The problem could be in the way that you do the pd.read_csv( ) command.

Comment: `survived` is the index.

Comment: Sure,  
training_data = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/train.csv')
testing_data = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-datasets/titanic/eval.csv')  this is how i have defined the read_csv() command

Comment: I used the df=df.reset_index() command as instructed by @BigBen and It worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I used the dataframe = dataframe.reset_index() method and the error was resolved.

Credits: @BigBen